# Filter out objects from queryset only if another object is in queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset

Considering a very simple model as such:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    attribute = models.IntegerField(choices=[1,2,3])
```

I would like all Things, except those with attribute=2.
But I do want these with attribute=2 if there is no Things with attribute other than 2 in the result set.

How can I get this result with a single query?

[Edit]
Actually I only need the first Thing that has an attribute different than 2, or the first thing with an attribute of 2 if this is the only kind of Thing available.

I have been able to achieve that with a function as

```
def get_thing():
    things_per_attribute = [
        Thing.objects.filter(attribute=value)
        for value in [1, 3, 2]
    ]
    for thing in things_per_attribute:
        if thing.count() > 0:
            return thing[0]
    return None
```

I am still interested to see if anyone can propose a 1-query-solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One query:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, Case, When

Thing.objects.annotate(
    attribute_is_two=Case(
        When(attribute=2, then=True),
        default=False,
        output_field=BooleanField()
    ),
).order_by('-attribute_is_two').first()
```

Two queries:

```
def get_thing():
    thing = Things.objects.exclude(attribute=2).first()
    if thing:
         return thing
    return Thing.objects.first()
```

Comment: Yep, that seems great, thanks! Although we actually don't need the `filter(attribute=2)` in the last return call.

Comment: @ThierryJ. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend using `if thing.exists()` rather than `if thing`. Using the latter will evaluate the query while the former maintains queryset laziness.

Comment: @Justin `exists()` evaluates query.

Comment: You're right - I guess I misremembered the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#exists) then - my apologies. In any case, it recommends use of `.exists()` on querysets, but since it's only one object, I suppose it doesn't matter in that regard.

Comment: @Justin Yes, `queryset.exists()` is more efficient than `bool(queryset)`, but if we need `queryset` later, it is better to use `if queryset: do_something_with_queryset()` (one query), than `if queryset.exists(): do_something_with_queryset()` (two queries). Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't `if queryset:` also evaluate it, though?

Comment: @Justin Yes, it does, but result of evaluation is cached https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets

Comment: In this case, `.first()` has already evaluated the queryset and return either the object or `None`.